# How can I swap two inventory slots dynamically?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to use command blocks to swap the contents of two specific inventory slots dynamically, while retaining the item, data value, and stack size. I know it is possible to set a slot to contain a specific item, but I am unsure as to whether or not it is possible to switch them (without a ridiculous amount of command blocks, accounting for every possible item in the game). Is this possible?

Comment: Can you detect what is in a slot and store it in a scoreboard? _Spoiler: Haven't used cmds in a while_

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. Not that I know of.

Comment: I'll go and investigate, do you have a limit on how many command blocks you are willing to use?

Answer (score 1):

Possible as of 1.14, which allows you to use the new `/data modify` command to copy NBT between sources.

You need to have three commands per slot: one to copy the ID, one to copy the Count, and one to copy the `tag` compound (which stores the item's other data). You don't want to copy the `Slot` tag because it'll mess things up. Instead, you'll rely on it for selecting which slots to modify.

It won't be this easy though. Coding practice says you need a third temporary location when you swap two values. So free up a third slot in the block you want to modify as a utility slot. In this case, I'm going to swap slots 0 and 1 of the chest at coordinates (12, 23, 34) with my utility slot at slot 0 of block (0, 0, 0). Make sure to place one piece of dirt in the utility slot.

```
data modify block 0 0 0 Items[0].id set from block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:0b}].id
data modify block 0 0 0 Items[0].Count set from block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:0b}].Count
data modify block 0 0 0 Items[0].tag set from block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:0b}].tag

data modify block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:0b}].id set from block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:1b}].id
data modify block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:0b}].Count set from block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:1b}].Count
data modify block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:0b}].tag set from block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:1b}].tag

data modify block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:1b}].id set from block 0 0 0 Items[0].id
data modify block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:1b}].Count set from block 0 0 0 Items[0].Count
data modify block 12 23 34 Items[{Slot:1b}].tag set from block 0 0 0 Items[0].tag
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember whether the 10th hotbar slot came up in 1.9 or 1.10, but if you are running one of those you can press <kbd>F</kbd> (or your set button) to toggle the blocks in your hand and the 10th slot.

Comment: This works, but it's not what I'm asking for. I want to do this for any two slots using a command block, as indicated by the `minecraft-commands` tag.

Comment: BTW, it's 1.9. I haven't played MC since the 1.9 betas, and I remember being amazed at the 10th slot and the new arrows (and shulkers).

Comment: it was 1.9, along with shields and attack speeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mod to do it. For example, [hotbarswapper](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/1290946-hotbarswapper-swap-the-contents-of-your-hotbar). It involves no command blocks just if you want to use it on a real server like Hypixel or Mineplex you will most likely be banned for "unauthorized mods." By holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scrolling, you can swap the bars in your inventory, up or down.

Comment: This isn't what the question is asking for. The question is asking for a way to swap slips slots on command, not when the player wants to.